# Joining SQL Tables

Tags: sql, join, merge, union

I have two tables:

RecommendedFriends and AddedFriends

each of the tables have a User field and a Friend field. I am trying to figure out how I can see how many friends a User added that they were also recommended. Heres an example of the tables:

```
RecommendedFriends
User    Friends     Time
------------------------------------
Jake    Eric        8:00am
Jake    John        8:00am
Jake    Jack        8:30am
Greg    John        8:30am
Greg    Tim         9:00am
Greg    Steve       9:30am
Will    Jackson     9:30am

AddedFriends
User    Friends     Time
------------------------------------
Jake    Jack        8:35am
Greg    John        8:35am
Greg    Tim         9:00pm
Greg    Jim         10:30am
Greg    Tina        10:45am
Greg    Bob         10:00am
Charlie Brian       11:00am
```

So the table I need would look like this:

```
Results
User    RecFriends  AddFriends   
------------------------------------
Jake    Eric        
Jake    John        
Jake    Jack        Jack
Greg    John        John
Greg    Tim         Tim
Greg    Steve       
Greg                Tina
Will    Jackson     
Charlie             Brian
```

So I can go in and say 3 people added friends they were recommended, 4 Recommendations failed, and 2 people added someone they weren't recommended.

Comment: On the table RecommendedFriends table, USER was recommended FRIENDS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(rf.USER, af.user) as user, rf.friends as RecFriends, af.Friends as AddFriends,
from RecommendedFriends rf full outer join
     AddedFriends af
     on rf.user = af.user and
        rf.Friends = af.Friends
```

This doesn't take time into account.  You might want to check that the time of the add is after the time of the recommendation, if you want to infer causality between the recommendation and the add.

If you are using a database that doesn't support `full outer join` (can anyone say "MySQL"), you can get the same result doing:

```
select t.user, MAX(case when which = 'rec' then friends end) as RecFriends,
       MAX(case when which = 'add' then friends end) as AddFriends
from ((select rf.user, rf.friends, 'rec' as which
       from RecommendedFriends af.user
      ) union all
      (select af.user, af.friends, 'add' as which
       from AddedFriends af
      )
     ) t
group by user
```

This version has the nice feature that it will not produce duplicate records, in the event of multiple recommendations or adds.

Comment: perhaps add `af.time > rf.time` so that it only includes adds after recommendations